# Example for Email User Interface Implementation Like Followup.cc

Tags: email, user-interface

I want to create a new software that can be controlled by email.

It will work like followup.cc or followupthen.com.

The users of these softwares can give commands to the system by using only email. For example, sending an email to `1minute@followup.cc` sets the system to send a notification email after **1 minute**. Or sending an email to `4weeks@followup.cc` sets the system to send a notification email after **4 weeks**.

I have never seen an example for implementing such an email user interface. I don't know where to start. Do you know of any good tutorial or open source code that I can take as example?

Note: I appreciate anything useful but my preferred programming languages are python or java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [SubEthaSMTP](http://code.google.com/p/subethasmtp/) library to receive mail. That gives you the SMTP envelope information: reverse-path (usually the sender's email address), recipient and message content as a stream.

Based on your question it seems that you do not need to parse the message (for example to retrieve the subject), but if do need, then parse the mail using the [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) library.

You can find example code in the SubEthaSMTP wiki pages. A more complex example is [SubEtha Mail](http://code.google.com/p/subetha/), a mail list manager.